# DataTables get array data of cells of selected rows Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using the select plugin, I'm trying to get the data from the selected rows using `rows().data()` but the data it pulls is much more than the array of cell data, I want to submit that data in a Ajax POST request, but I'm getting a 413 error saying "request entity too large".

https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

```
var dataTable = $('#products').DataTable( {
  "processing": true,
  "ajax": "/products",
  "columns": [
    {
      "className": 'select-checkbox',
      "defaultContent": '<span style="display:none;">0</span>',
      "orderDataType": "dom-text",
      type: 'string'
    },
    {
      "data": "sku",
      "className": 'sku-value',
      "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
      "data": "name",
      "className": 'name-value',
      "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
      "data": "our_price",
      "className": 'our-price-value price',
      "defaultContent": 0
    },
    {
      "data": "sale_price",
      "className": 'sale-price-value price',
      "defaultContent": 0
    },
    {
      "data": "rrp_price",
      "className": 'rrp-price-value price',
      "defaultContent": 0
    },
    {
      "data": "similar_price",
      "className": 'similar-price-value price',
      "defaultContent": 0
    },
    {
      "data": "stores.one.store",
      "className": 'store-one store',
      "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
      "data": "stores.two.store",
      "className": 'store-two store',
      "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
      "data": "stores.three.store",
      "className": 'store-three store',
      "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
      "data": "end_date",
      "className": 'end-date-value date',
      "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
      "data": "updated_at",
      "className": 'updated-at-value date',
      "defaultContent": ""
     }
  ],
  "select": {
    "style":    'multi',
    "selector": 'td:first-child'
  },
});

var rowData = dataTable.rows( { selected: true } ).data();
```

But from 3 rows selected with 5 cells with some very small values, Chrome dev tools freezes up trying to load it all, as somehow that value also contains all 2200 rows in the table as well. :/

My code is taken from here: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html

In the object that rowData is there's a array mixed in with a heap of other functions, the array has all the data I need, but I cant separate it form all the other stuff.

The data inside rowData:
[image]

I just want those first 3 lines, the array.

To pass to:

```
$.post('/generate', rowData, function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Can you post your datatable definition

Comment: What do you mean by definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

API method [`rows().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.data%28%29) returns Array-like object which is also DataTables API instance.

Use [`toArray()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/toArray%28%29) API method to convert API instance to native Javascript array object.

```
var rowData = dataTable.rows( { selected: true } ).data().toArray();
```